# Do I need to use reactive stack in order to use RSocket

Tags: spring-boot, rsocket

I develop a mobile app using Flutter and backend using Spring boot and JPA.

I've notice while developing that I need Websocket and then came across RSocket.

Do I need to change my persistent stack (Hibernate,JPA and postgres) to use RSocket ?

Answer (score 0):

you don`t need to change persistent stack, but you will have another driver(**reactive one**) to connect from your app to Postgresql.

[r2dbc-postgresql](https://github.com/pgjdbc/r2dbc-postgresql)

And also some changes in your application

[spring-data-r2dbc](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc)

[r2dbc docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: I already have JPA modeling and query tested and working . do I need to change all of that?

Comment: yes, because you will have reactive stack  and without changing driver to database and some query changes, your reactive stack will be blocking one.

Comment: I see..and If I use different scheduler to preform the JPA queries?

Comment: Check some articles about Threads and Schedulers in reactive programming